# update from local servers

Tags: server, updates

When i choose update from local servers and 
especially from locations like private servers 
hosted by various firms or universities,

are all latest updates available ?

how can we be secure than no crap or irrelevant software
is pushed from local servers ? is there any check taking
place regarding the validity of local servers ?

if all local servers are identical images of Main Server,
there is no need to specify location at updates,
it could be resolved on domain level and
everyone could enjoy best update speed available automatically

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> are all latest updates available ?

Depends on how often that server synchronizes from upstream sources. There will be a delay, but how large differs from site to site. This is what is written in Ubuntu's [mirror information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors):

> Keep up to date. Please try to mirror about four times a day (so every six hours) for archive mirrors. Since Ubuntu only releases every six months or so, a daily check on a releases mirror is sufficient. Push mirroring is available as an alternative.

So I'd expect the maximum delay to be less than half a day, as they encourage mirrors to  sync four times a day.

> how can we be secure than no crap or irrelevant software is pushed from local servers ? is there any check taking place regarding the validity of local servers ?

All packages are signed. Packages that is signed by a key that is not trusted by your system will as a minimum generate a warning that you're about to install an unauthenticated package, or it will refuse to install it.

> if all local servers are identical images of Main Server, there is no need to specify location at updates, it could be resolved on domain level and everyone could enjoy best update speed available automatically

That is one approach, but it's not bulletproof. There may be reasons to override automatic choices. Historically things like DNS-based geo-mirroring was not cheaply available, or easy to implement. Thus national mirrors for Linux distributions became quite commonplace.

Comment: Nowadays there is enough mature affordable technology to achieve this automatic geo-mirroring. I have been pushing the main server and world traffic for years because i thought the locals were not updated with latest versions... i bet many users will be doing this mistake

Comment: Which is probably not a huge problem. They are fairly well scaled, and can handle the traffic. Worst case is that you get slower downloads, which is also not a **big** deal.

Comment: are you 1000% sure that no crap packages can be pushed from local servers ? imagine if someone could sign packages and relations between famous and crap packages

Comment: The package signing keys are managed centrally by Canonical. They are probably one of the must guarded secrets the company has, as they may destroy all trust anyone has in the company.

Comment: sounds safe... with some simple tricks like local geo-mirroring, worldwide internet traffic can be cut down even to half of it